# How to pass a value throgh a modal pop up using the jquery method POST

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question to ask.
I have very little knowledge on the jQuery framework, so I can not figure out how to pass a value through the POST method then to be displayed in a modal pop up.
Pressing on the link below I recover the value of the id, which I can show in the pop up.

```
<div id='basic-modal'>
<a href="?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"  data-mydata="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class='basic'>Show</a>
</div>
```

This is the jqueryScript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
$('#basic-modal-content').text($(this).data('mydata')).modal();
return false;
});
});
```

Now I want to pass that value to a file named check.php to show in the pop up the result of a MySQL SELECT processed within the file check.php.

```
<script>
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
$('#basic-modal-content').modal();
var id= data('mydata');

$.post("test.php",{ name:id},function(ajaxresult){
$("#basic-modal-content").html(ajaxresult);
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The script above obviously is doesn't provide the wanted.
Could you kindly help me to figure out how to run the script correctly?

Thank you

Comment: `.data('mydata')` seems wrong. The attribute is called `data-mydata` and ir is an _attribute_, so you should use `.attr('data-mydata')`

Comment: I don't know the `modal()` function, what is this ?

Comment: Hi Apollo, thanks for your answer. I tried to follow your suggestion, but the script does not work. I found the modal() function in this page http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/